# MySQL GROUPBY show newest row

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a messaging system I am working on that receives messages from my Facebook Business Page and stores the information in my database.  The information provided in the callback is a Sender ID, Recipient ID, and message data.  I am wanting to group all messages between the sender and recipient together and return only the newest result (by row ID number) at the top of the list.

For example :

```
ID | Sender ID  |   Recipient ID  | is_read
1  | 67890      |   12345         | 1
2  | 23232      |   12345         | 0
3  | 12345      |   67890         | 1
4  | 67890      |   12345         | 0
5  | 12345      |   23232         | 1
6  | 55555      |   12345         | 1
```

I don't want to show any results with Sender ID "12345".

The result I need should look something like this

```
Result | Row ID  |   Sender ID
1      | 4       |   67890
2      | 2       |   23232
3      | 6       |   55555
```

Here is my current query.  Should return an Array with the newest message first no matter the senderid order.  Currently, I get random results.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, senderid, sender_name, is_read FROM (SELECT id, senderid, sender_name, is_read FROM FB WHERE senderid != '".$fb_page_id."' GROUP BY senderid) AS f ORDER BY is_read ASC LIMIT ".$page_num * $perpage.", ".$perpage;
```

This has to be something simple.... just can't figure it out... lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the sender and its latest id in the resultset, we can just use aggregation here:

```
select max(id) as last_id, sender_id
from fb
where sender_id != 12345
group by sender_id
order by last_id desc
```

If, on the other hand, you need the *entire* latest row per sender, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select fb.*, row_number() over(partition by sender_id order by id desc) rn
    from fb 
    where sender_id != 12345
) f
where rn = 1
order by id desc
```

You can add the `limit` clause after the `order by` if that's needed.

In MySQL < 8.0, where window functions are not supported, we can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
select *
from fb f
where sender_id != 12345 and id = (
    select max(f1.id) from fb f1 where f1.sender_id = f.sender_id
)
order by id desc
```

Comment: I changed the code to : $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) AS last_id, senderid, sender_name, DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(the_time, '+00:00','+01:00'), '%c/%d/%y %l:%i%p') AS the_time, data, is_read FROM FB WHERE senderid != '".$fb_page_id."' GROUP BY senderid ORDER BY last_id DESC LIMIT ".$page_num * $perpage.", ".$perpage;  and now I don't get the latest reply at all.

Comment: @EagleTalonTim: this is a different query.. Please run the query as provided first, before integrating it into your application code - so you can see what it actually produces.

Comment: It should be exactly the same query, just with more results that are required in the rest of my code.  I also tried the second option and got an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by senderid order by id desc)....."

Comment: @EagleTalonTim: ok. (1) If you want more columns than in the first query, then you need filtering, not aggregation, as explained in the answer. (2) The error you receive with the second query indicates that you are running an old version of MySQL ; I updated my answer with an alternative to the 2nd query.